# CA-signed SSL certificate not trusted, claims self-signed

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I just tried to install SSL certificate from RapidSSL.

On email arrived domain.key, domain.csr and certificate.

On first place, I used openssl x509 to generate ssl.crt 
so I edited nginx.conf with this

```
ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/your_domain_name.crt
ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/your_domain_name.key;
```

I also tried `ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/ssl.crt`

But browsers still wont trust my certificate.

Comment: There is a difference between 'won't sign' and 'won't trust'. Which is it?

Comment: Ah, sorry then. Well serverr is just saying, the certificate is sign by server itself.

Comment: So fix your question. If you want an answer, that is. NB That's not accurate either. It says the certificate is *signed* by the server itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that it's possible to make head or tail of your question, assuming my edits are correct, the behaviour you describe can only result from deploying the original certificate you generated instead of the signed certificate provided by the CA. Possibly you also need to restart your server at the appropriate time as well.